# Нужно предугадать результат рекурсии. Java

Tags: java, рекурсия

Не совсем понимаю как работает рекурсия.
Как предугадать, какой результат даст эта рекурсия?

```java
static int rec(int a) {
    if (a == 40)
        return a;
    else
        return (a + rec(a*2));
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(rec(5));
}
```

Comment: Запустите и узнаете. Или воспользуйтесь отладчиком. Или нарисуйте значения входного /выходного параметров на бумажке.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Начинаем отсюда:

```
main(){
 System.out.println(rec(5));
}
```

Теперь рассмотрим функцию. Переменная `a`, переданная в функцию = 5.

```
int rec(int a)
```

Рассмотрим условие:

```
 if (a == 40)
 return a;
```

Так как a = 5, то условие ложно, следовательно переходим в секцию `else`.

```
return (a + rec(a*2);
```

Как видно, мы возвращаем 5 + rec(5 * 2). Заметим, что так как функция выполняется рекурсивно, то итоговый результат не будет получен, пока рекурсивные вызовы rec() не будут обработаны и посчитаны полностью. Иными словами, рекурсивные вызовы закончатся тогда, когда входной параметр a будет равен 40.

Трассировка будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
5 + rec(5 * 2) => 5 + 10 + rec(10 * 2) => 5 + 10 + 20 + rec(20 * 2) => 5 + 10 + 20 + 40 = 75
```

P.S. Надеюсь не ошибся в вычислениях xD

Answer (score 0):

Предположим, что рекурсия всё-таки завершается.
Тогда последний вызов: `rec(40) = 40`
Вызов с аргументом 40 может быть только прямым или из `rec(20)`, который вернёт `20+rec(40)`

Итак,

```
rec(40) = 40
rec(20) = 20 + 40 = 60
rec(10) = 10 + 60 = 70
rec(5)  =  5 + 70 = 75
```

<sub>Нетрудно понять, что для любых других целых аргументов рекурсия не завершится.</sub>